# Swift / Objective C: Is there a way to find all objects of a certain type?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I understand this might be bad software designing but I am mostly curious if this is possible without actually using it in a live app.

In Swift / Objective C: Is there a quick performant way to find all objects of a certain type? Lets say I want all objects which are currently referenced of type UIViewController. Is this possible?

Comment: "currently referenced", are you talking runtime?

Comment: No. There is not without changing the object to somehow record its instance somehow (such as a global array). For view controllers that are in the view stack you could start with the scenes root view controller and work forward

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes, runtime.

Comment: If you want to debug which objects are still in memory and which objects might be keeping strong references to them, you might pause execution and  use the [memory graph](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/improving_your_app_s_performance/reducing_your_app_s_memory_use/gathering_information_about_memory_use/). You can see which objects are still in memory and which other object might be keeping reference to it.

Comment: @Rob I am aware of that method but I was looking for something which can be done in the app itself.